# can not access memory when accessing pointer to a struct GDB error

Tags: c, gdb

I have run gdb, as my code show segfault. I understand that the code that give the error is

```
210         if (colour_s->colorlist.colorlist_id == 1)
(gdb) print colour_s
$1 = (car_colour_list_t_slot *) 0x21
(gdb) print colorlist
$2 = (car_colour_list_t *) 0x12d1a80
(gdb) print colour_s->colorlist
Cannot access memory at address 0x21

typedef struct {
    int colorlist_id;
} car_colour_list_t;


typedef struct _car_colour_list_t_slot {
    car_colour_list_t colorlist;
    struct _car_colour_list_t_slot *next, *prev;
} car_colour_list_t_slot;


car_colour_list_t_slot *colour_s;
colour_s = (car_colour_list_t_slot *)malloc(sizeof(car_colour_list_t_slot));
car_colour_list_t *colorlist;
colorlist = (car_colour_list_t *)malloc(sizeof(car_colour_list_t));
```

I have already assigned those pointers memory, but when I tried to print colour_s->colorlist it fails (can not access memory at address 0x21)

Can anyone understand why this happens, although I have already assign memory to each poitner?

Thank you

Comment: You are most certainly overwriting `color_s` directly or indirectly somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I assign it in one function, freed the colour_s pointer, and using socket, this value traverse to other functions (so a lot of things happened with this value). I just need to 'revoke' this value in my function.

Comment: We can't really guess what you're doing wrong. The lines you show are ok. So your error is elsewhere.

Comment: @Mat : the thing is I do not use this colour_s pointer to a struct in my function. It might be used by other function before (which is in remote server, maybe it is not freed or something). How can I then use this pointer to this struct again? I tried to set this pointer to NULL, but still does not help

Comment: Print the value of `color_s` (with the `%p` printf specifier) just after you malloc it, recompile and rerun your code. If the value printed by gdb when you segfault is not the same, then you will be 100% certain that you are modifying that variable _somewhere_ in your code, directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `colour_s` pointer is *definitely invalid.*  There is no doubt about it.  GDB is simply informing you of this fact.  (Any pointer near 0x0 is invalid, and any pointer with a residue modulo 4 is invalid for your structure.)  The `malloc` function will *never* return 0x21.

There are lots of ways your program can do this.  They boil down to two basic types of errors in your program:

- `colour_s` was not initialized.
- `colour_s` was initialized, but it was accidentally overwritten by an error in a different part of your code.
- <s>there is an error in GDB or your compiler</s> (not worth considering)

Run your program with Valgrind or set a watchpoint on `colour_s`.  These will help you discover where the error is in your code.

As an alternative exercise, see if you can find the error just by reading your code, without running it.  Read carefully.  This kind of exercise will make you a better programmer.

Comment: I already assign memory to the pointer, and I am sure that in my code, I did not assign this variable at all..

Comment: @heike: If you are sure that it is initialized, then the only other possibility is that your program changes the value after it is initialized.  This can happen through pointers to unrelated variables if the pointers are used incorrectly.  It is a common type of error in C.  As I said, set a watchpoint or run Valgrind.